# Help loading large Images in  UIWebview?

Tags: iphone, ipad, memory-management, uiscrollview

I am loading images in UIWebview using the following code. For each image (while scrolling my scrollview) a function is called to load the image. The problem is that when I am continuously scrolling up to 30 images the application crashes. What may be the reason? My images are 1300 by 1200 pixels. Please help me find a solution.

```
- (void) loadCatalogImage 
{
    @try{
//  if(imgView.image != nil)
//      return;
    //  [global_imgProgress startAnimating];
    //NSLog(@"image loading at = %@, %d", baseURL, 2 + pageNo);
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool;
    pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    //NSArray *array = [global_ContentString componentsSeparatedByString:@"@@#"];
    NSArray *array1 = [catalogURL componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
    //NSLog(@"baseURL = %@",baseURL);
    NSLog(@"loading catalog image(method: loadCatalogImage).......%@%@",baseURL, [[[array1 objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@"##"] objectAtIndex:0]); 

    zoomedImageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", baseURL, [[[array1 objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@"##"] objectAtIndex:1]];
//  NSLog(@"Catalog ZOOM URL = %@", zoomedImageURL);//[[array1 objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@"##"]);//[[[array objectAtIndex:[[global_CatalogRef objectAtIndex:pageNo] intValue]] componentsSeparatedByString:@"##"] objectAtIndex:3]);
    [zoomedImageURL retain];

    NSLog(@"aaaaaaa = %@",zoomedImageURL);
    [webView loadRequest:
        [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
            [NSURL URLWithString:
                [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",baseURL, [[[array1 objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@"##"] objectAtIndex:1]
                ]
            ]]
        ];

    }
}
```

Comment: What stack trace or crash info do you get on the console? Is your project producing any warnings?

Comment: Just FYI : You're not releasing the pool you're creating.

Comment: @Madhumitha: What was your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any app that loads up enough resources to occupy so much memory will crash. Apple has several demo projects that deal specifically with loading a large image by breaking it down into smaller bits ci suggest you take a look at them.

Comment: Do you have an example? Can you add a link?

Answer (score 1):

Your images are 1300 x 1200 and you're loading 30 of them? You <strike>may</strike> WILL be running out of memory. If your app is ignoring memory warnings, and hogging up memory, the iOS system may be forcing your app to quit. As I mention in my comment below, that many images, that size, would be about 180megs. Far too big.

Do you really need to deliver such large images to an iphone app, and so many of them?

Comment: the image size  is the problem..?

Comment: As I said, you may be running out of memory. Can't say for sure, but it's a likely candidate!

Comment: I ask again: "Do you really need to deliver such large images to an iphone app, and so many of them?". An iPhone has memory limits which you can't step around! You need to compromise. 30 images of that size just isn't going to work. If you insist on having 30 huge images, you will continue to struggle!

Comment: there is any restriction for image size..?i have read from apple document that it should not be larger than 1024X1024.but while am loading the image size of 768X900,its getting crashed.

Comment: There is a restriction on memory size. I don't know how to say this any more directly than this: computers don't have infinite memory. When you load a 1300x1200 image it probably occupies 1300x1200x4 bytes of memory. That's about 6megs. 30x6 is 180megs. That's far far far more memory than you should be trying to use in an iphone app. A good rule of thumb is to try to keep under 20megs memory if possible.

Comment: If you're loading huge images, you can get away with loading a few, but it's crucial to unload the images that aren't needed any more as soon as you can. Otherwise, no memory left, and oops it crashed again...

Answer (score 0):

Can you put a crash log please? If possible Enable the Environment variable 'NSZombieEnabled' and then run the application and have a look at the crash log. This will help us to get the exact problem. By the way why are you creating and retaining "zoomedImageURL"?

Comment: when it crashes, the console says like "The Debugger has exited with status 0".am using zoomedImageURL in another place .so am retaining that.

Comment: Does the console say anything else interesting? Such as "Received memory warning" or similar?

Comment: @occulus:yes.. am getting the same.

Comment: Then you are indeed running out of memory, which is not surprising when loading 30 huge images.

Comment: Btw, whenever you are asking a question, always include any interesting console output as part of a question. It saves everyone time.

Comment: "exited with status 0" indeed means that your app is running out of memory, suggestion would be reduce the image size to only how much is needed, and don't load 30+ images at one time, instead load only few images which will visible to user.